# NAT linux box to windows

Tags: iptables, nat

I have this 2 network interfaces linux box - eth0 : 192.168.1.1 (internet access), eth1 : 192.168.10.1 (local network access), configured as follow with iptables and a windows one.

```
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N LOG_ACCEPT
-N LOG_DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j LOG_ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG_DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j LOG_ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOG_DROP
-A LOG_ACCEPT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES ACCEPT : "
-A LOG_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT
-A LOG_DROP -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES DROP : " --log-level 7
-A LOG_DROP -j DROP

sudo iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

windows 
static ip : 192.168.10.2
mask      : 255.255.255.0
gateway   : 192.168.10.1
dns       : 192.168.10.1
```

And I don't get  why it does not work : the windows box seems to have packets running through its system but I can't browse the internet nor ping the internet.

Thanks

Comment: Is `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` set?

Comment: yes it is, in sysctl.conf and /etc/rc.d/init.d/network script

Comment: here are general rules on how to deal with network problems: https://serverfault.com/a/885958/387342 . There's a lot of diagostics and reducing that you can do.

Comment: Add rules to allow ICMP input on the Linux router. Can you then ping the router from the Windows machine? Can the router ping "the internet"? What do you see if you run tcpdump on the router with `-i any` while trying to ping from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

On the windows machine, I think you sould use the DNS servers from you're ISP, based on the information of you`re iptables config.
If you have a DHCP server on the linux server machine you sould use domain-name-servers alocation of you're ISP like:

```
option domain-name-servers      ISP-DNS1.example, ISP-DNS2.example;
```

This sould solve you're issue.

Comment: What does the question have to do with DNS? The poster is troubleshooting basic layer 3 connectivity.

Comment: Shure is troubleshooting basic layer 3 connectivity, and he can't browse the internet nor ping the internet. Could be a problem with the DNS cause does not resolve the hostnames.